# How Dynamicaly columns in UNPIVOT operator

Tags: t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, parameter-passing, unpivot

I currently have the following query:

```
WITH History AS (
    SELECT
        kz.*,
        kz.__$operation AS operation,
        map.tran_begin_time as beginT, 
        map.tran_end_time as endT
    FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh(sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all') AS kz 
        INNER JOIN  [cdc].[lsn_time_mapping] map
    ON kz.[__$start_lsn] = map.start_lsn
    where kz.GUID_BalanceHC_Zalezh = 'DDA9AB3A-A0AF-4623-9362-0000C8C83D63'
),
UnpivotedValues AS(
    SELECT  guid, GUID_another, field, val, operation, beginT, endT 
    FROM History
        UNPIVOT ( [val] FOR field IN
        (
            area, 
            oilwidthmin, 
            oilwidthmax, 
            efectivwidthmin, 
            efectivwidthmax, 
            etc...
        ))t
),
UnpivotedWithLastValue AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        --Use LAG() to get the last value for the same field
        LAG(val, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY guid, GUID_another, field ORDER BY BeginT) LastVal
    FROM UnpivotedValues
)
SELECT * FROM UnpivotedWithLastValue WHERE val <> LastVal OR LastVal IS NULL ORDER BY guid
```

This query returns the changed values for a single table that has CDC (Change Data Capture) enabled.
I want to create a stored procedure that receives the columns to be unpivoted, and the cdc function (e.g. cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_...) as parameters and returns the result set.

The result for this tables must be joined in one report.

In my case parameter 1 is `cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh(sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all')`. This is the CDC function.
How should I send the list of fields that i want in the result?  How's the string?
Also, is there a way to do without dynamic SQL? Dynamic SQL it is not better solution for performance.

Comment: Can you provide an overview of what you expect the stored procedure to receive (parameters) and to return (data result set).
E.g. should the procedure work on multiple CDC tables at a time (i.e. receive a list of tables as a parameter), or do you expect to call the procedure one time for each CDC table?

Answer (score 1):

As you know SQL Server is declarative by design and does not support macro substitution.

**UNPIVOT would clearly be more performant**, but here is a simplified example of a UNPIVOT which does not require Dynamic SQL, but only a little XML.

**Example**

Let's assume your table/results looks like this:

[image]

You may notice that I only we only specify key fields to EXCLUDE in the final WHERE

```
Declare @YourData table (ID int,Active bit,First_Name varchar(50),Last_Name varchar(50),EMail varchar(50),Salary decimal(10,2))
Insert into @YourData values
(1,1,'John','Smith','john.smith@email.com',85600),
(2,0,'Jane','Doe'  ,'jane.doe@email.com',83200)

;with cte as (
    -- Replace with your Complex Query
    Select * from @YourData
)
Select A.ID
      ,A.Active
      ,C.*
 From  cte A
 Cross Apply (Select XMLData=cast((Select A.* for XML RAW) as xml)) B
 Cross Apply (
                Select Item   = attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)')
                      ,Value  = attr.value('.','varchar(max)') 
                 From  XMLData.nodes('/row')    C1(n)
                 Cross Apply C1.n.nodes('./@*') C2(attr)
                 Where attr.value('local-name(.)','varchar(100)') not in ('ID','Active')
              ) C
```

**Returns**

[image]